# Select Distinct from joined table

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox, distinct

I have two tables here, Fixture and Report. Both of these contain a FixtureID field. I'm trying to create a function that will fill my combobox with a list of unique FixtureID's. Each individual FixtureID represents multiple ReportID's (from the Report table).

My first attempt fills the combobox with every FixtureID available to the selected scout, for each ReportID involved in that Fixture. For example, if 4 reports were made for a fixture, the same fixture (displaying report date) is shown 4 times, I just need it to be shown once. In this case I've used my Report class instead of Fixture, as it displays the ReportDate from the Report table.

```
Report    |Fixture                       FixtureID = 1--> ReportID 1 
__________|________                                       ReportID 2 
FixtureID |FixtureID                                      ReportID 3 
ReportID  |HomeTeamID                                     ReportID 4                     
ScoutID   |AwayTeamID                    
ReportDate|                              FixtureID = 2--> ReportID 5
                                                          ReportID 6
```

In this example, the combobox would display 1 and 2 for Fixture IDs.

First attempt:

```
'Filters reports based on the selected scout
        Public Function filterFixtureReports() As List(Of Report)
            'DISTINCT Report.FixtureID or Report.ReportDate not working
            Dim typeList As New List(Of Report)
            Dim Str As String = _
           <String> SELECT
                        * 
                    FROM 
                        Report 
                    WHERE
                        ScoutID = (<%= UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbScoutName.SelectedItem.ScoutID %>)
                    ORDER BY 
                        ReportDate      
           </String>
            Try
                Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DBConnection)
                    conn.Open()
                    Using cmdQuery As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Str, conn)
                        Using drResult As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader()
                            While drResult.Read
                                typeList.Add(New Report(drResult("ReportID"), drResult("ScoutID"), drResult("FixtureID"), drResult("PlayerID"), drResult("ReportDate")))
                            End While
                        End Using 'Automatically closes connection
                    End Using
                End Using

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Report Exception: " & ex.Message & vbNewLine & Str)
            End Try

            Return typeList
        End Function
```

My second attempt uses the Fixture class, but only zero's are returned instead of individual FixtureID's.

Second attempt:

```
Public Function filterFixtures() As List(Of Fixture)
        'DISTINCT Report.FixtureID or Report.ReportDate not working
        Dim typeList As New List(Of Fixture)
        Dim Str As String = _
       <String> SELECT
                    DISTINCT Fixture.FixtureID,
                    * 
                FROM 
                    Fixture
                INNER JOIN Report ON Report.FixtureID = Fixture.FixtureID
                WHERE
                    Report.ScoutID = (<%= UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbScoutName.SelectedItem.ScoutID %>)
                ORDER BY 
                    Report.ReportDate      
       </String>
        Try
            Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DBConnection)
                conn.Open()
                Using cmdQuery As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Str, conn)
                    Using drResult As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader()
                        While drResult.Read
                            typeList.Add(New Fixture(drResult("FixtureID")) With {
                                         .HomeTeamID = drResult("HomeTeamID"),
                                         .AwayTeamID = drResult("AwayTeamID")})
                        End While
                    End Using 'Automatically closes connection
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Report Exception: " & ex.Message & vbNewLine & Str)
        End Try

        Return typeList
    End Function
```

Comment: Please provide sale data and example of what the final result should look like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've changed the question to reflect how the Fixtures and Reports work.

Answer (score 0):

High Level Process

1. Select Scout from 1st combo box. (Not covered below.)
2. Use Scout Id to generate list of FixtureIds
3. Use the FixtureId and ScoutID to identify the correct reports

---

**2. Use Scout Id to generate list of FixtureIds**  -Use this to populate the 2nd combo box.

```
SELECT FixtureId, MAX(reportdate)
FROM  Report
WHERE ScoutID = (<%= UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbScoutName.SelectedItem.ScoutID %>)
GROUP BY FixtureId
```

---

**3. Use the FixtureId and ScoutID to identify the correct reports** - -Use this  to populate the 3nd combo box.

```
SELECT *
FROM  Report
WHERE ScoutID = (<%= UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbScoutName.SelectedItem.ScoutID %>)
AND FixtureID = <Fill in with 2nd combo box value>
ORDER BY ReportDate
```

> Note: If a FixtureID can only be associated to 1 scout, then 
>   ScoutID conditional is unnecessary in the above query.

Comment: Thank you for your help- this method gives me an error: "Column Report.ReportID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: I see where this would cause a problem within your code.  It is calling additional fields on this line: typeList.Add(New Report(drResult("ReportID"), drResult("ScoutID"), drResult("FixtureID"), drResult("PlayerID"), drResult("ReportDate")))  Should the box merely display Fixture1 and Fixture2?

Comment: If the answer to the above question is yes, you will want to modify your code for the combobox accordingly.

Comment: Once this combobox has been filled with FixtureIDs, it should set another combobox to display all of the ReportIDs that share the selected FixtureID. Is it possible to make this work, seeing as I still need to fill my Report typelist to get the correct information?

Comment: Yes, pass the FixtureId from the first box to the second.  This of course will require another query.

Comment: This query is already in place, as you said it just requires the FixtureID. However, eventually I'll need to set the display member of the original combobox, it won't remain as FixtureID- this is why I was retrieving ReportDate as well.

Comment: Updated query to include ReportDate in the select list.  Thank you for  clarifying what the final result should look like.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot get this working. The edit you gave suggests I should already have a FixtureID from the first box. There are three boxes- the first on is a list of scouts, selecting one of them produces a list of fixtures in the second box, selecting a fixture produces a list of reports in the third box. Selecting one FIxture (in the second box) should produce multiple reports that match the FixtureID

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is always applied to all selected columns. If you want 1 column to be distinct, only include that column, eg: `SELECT DISTINCT col FROM t1`.

Another way is to use `GROUP BY`, eg `SELECT col FROM t1 GROUP BY col`.

With group by you have a little bit more flexibility, because you can include aggregate functions like `MIN()` and `MAX()`.

This might be useful if you want to include arbitrary values for the other columns, eg `SELECT col1, MAX(col2) AS col2, MAX(col3) AS col3 FROM t1`.